# How do I find the image of $A = [-8,6]$ and the inverse image of $B = (5,26]$, when my function is $f(x) = 3\sqrt{100 - x^2} + 2$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The exercise states: 
Let $f(x) = 3\sqrt{(100 − x^{2})} + 2$. Determine the domain and the range for $f$. Find the image of $A = [−8, 6]$ $(f(A))$, and the inverse image of $B = (5, 26]$ $(f^{−1} (B))$. Justify your answers.

I know how to find the domain and range, I have done it, but I am pretty confused about how to find these images.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do it (which probably isn't what you are taught) is:

If $x \in [-8,6] \implies$

$-8 \le x \le 6$.

If $-8 \le x \le 0$ then $0 \le x^2 \le 64$ and if $0\le x \le 6$ then $0 \le x^2 \le 36$.  In either case we have $0 \le x^2 \le 64$.

So $-64 \le -x^2 \le 0$ and

$36 = 100 - 64 \le 100-x^2 \le 100$ so

$6 \le \sqrt {100 -x^2} \le 10$ and $

$20 =3*6+2 \le 3\sqrt{100-x^2}\le 3*10+2 = 32$ so

$20 \le f(x) \le 32$.

We can assume that $f$ is continuous and "hits" every point in between.

So $f([-8,6]) = [20, 32]$.

You might wonder but what happen to the $-8$ to $0$ values. They simply became redundant in the squaring.

....

To find the reverse image is much the same but backwards.

$5 < 3\sqrt{100 - x^2} + 2 \le 26\implies$

$3 < 3\sqrt{100-x^2} \le 24$ so$

$1 < \sqrt{100-x^2} \le 8$ so

$1 < 100 -x^2 \le 64$

$-99 < -x^2 \le -36$ so

$36 \le x^2 < 99$ So

$6 \le \sqrt {x^2} < \sqrt{99} = 3\sqrt{11}$.

Now do *NOT* make the mistake that $\sqrt {x^2} = x$!!!!!!  That isn't true.  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ so

$6 \le |x| < 3\sqrt{11}$.

If $x$ is positive then $6 \le x < 3\sqrt{11}$.

If $x$ is negative then $6 \le -x < 3\sqrt{11}$ and $-3\sqrt{11} < x \le -6$.  (And $x=0$ is impossible.)

So either $-3\sqrt{11} < x \le -6$  or $6 \le -x < 3\sqrt{11}$.

So the pre image is $(-3\sqrt{11},-6] \cup [6,3\sqrt{11})$.

Comment: In your last line, you meant to write $(-3\sqrt{11}, -6] \cup [6, 3\sqrt{11})$.